# Merge standard in and log file to standard out

Tags: linux, bash, log-files

I'm looking for a command or a bash script that can perform the following:

[image: supermerge image]

That is: I want a "supermerge" to merge the standard in stream  with contents written continuously to a log file (var/log/messages in this example). The result should be written to standard out.

The reason is to scans for certain error messages and these messages can both be written to a log file and to standard out.

For example:

```
my_strange_program /var/log/messages | supermerge /var/log/messages | my_log_scanner
```

- my_strange_program can send errors to standard out and the log file.
- supermerge - the script I'm looking for
- my_log_scanner a program that scans for error messages (I've already got that)

**Note:** The log files can rotate: messages, messages.1, messages.2 etc. So it is not possible to just `tail` the file, since it can be renamed.

Comment: `tail -F` will work with renamed files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_strange_program /var/log/messages > /tmp/tmpfile | tail -F /var/log/messages /tmp/tmpfile | my_log_scanner
```

Comment: If you're redirecting stdout (step1) how will tail (step2) read anything?

Comment: @Cristian: step 1 doesn't print anything to the pipe, and tail doesn't read anything from the pipe, so it works — here the pipe is just a confusing way of writing `&`. @Dennis: there's a possible race condition if `my_strange_program` writes more than 10 lines before `tail` is ready. Passing `-n +1` to `tail` will fix this, at the expense of showing `/var/log/messages` in full.

Comment: @Gilles: yes, you're right.

Comment: I have tested and this works. The only small problem is that tail does not die when the my_strange_program dies. I guess I can solve this with the tail parameter "--pid".

Comment: @Lennart: Yes, if you change the `|` to a `&` and do `tail --pid=$! ...` it should pick up the correct PID for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called multitee. It sounds like the thing you are looking for. I tried to figure out how it works but came to no working result

Another idea is to use multitail, if it is enough to get the merge on the screen

```
multitail -f /var/log/syslog -L "ping 4.2.2.1"
```